# How i can Attach a component under another component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

i want view two component in the same page, how i can do this? like:

```
<aura:component>
    bla bla bla
</aura:component>
<aura:component>
    bla bla bla
</aura:component>
```

and view it together

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this for using the component inside another component..

```
`<aura:component >
<c:Component2 />
<p class = "one">Hello World!</p>
<p>hello all!!</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to wrap it up under aura application. See this document 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_application.htm

Answer (score -1):

Thats not the correct way.

```
<!--c:CompOne-->
<aura:component>
your logic goes here
</aura:component>

<!--c:CompTwo-->
<aura:component extends="c:CompOne">
</aura:component>
```

> And next time to make sure you dont put unnecessarily things in your
>   code as you did..  blah blah this is not you put in your code.